# Gremlin .Net, filter vertices by property containing a value

Tags: c#, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I need to filter vertices in Azure Cosmos Graph DB by a property containing a value, I tried the code below but I am getting an error says (Unable to find any method 'filter')

```
var g = client.CreateTraversalSource();
var p = new P("containing", text);
var query = g.V().Filter(p).Range<Vertex>(page, pageSize);

var result = await client.ExcuteAsync<IEnumerable<Vertex>>(query);
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help someone else, I managed to figure it out with some help of a friend:

```
var p = new P("containing", text);
var query = g.V().has("propertyName", p).Range<Vertex>(page, pageSize);
var result = await client.ExecuteAsync<IEnumerable<Vertext>>(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still looking into this, there's predefined predicate values that can be used as string filters in the class TextP.

The above can be accomplished with the following:

```
var query = g.V().has("propertyName", TextP.Containing(text)).Range<Vertex>(page, pageSize);
var result = await client.ExecuteAsync<IEnumerable<Vertext>>(query);
```